# Can I Use RS232 Library For RS422 in PIC Microcontroller?

Tags: pic, c, serial, rs232, rs422

I have this project where I have to use RS422 and [Max485](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf) serial communication.

The task is simple: The input from 15 buttons should be send to PC by RS422 using [PIC18F4620](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/115982/MICROCHIP/PIC18F4620.html).

I have no experience in serial communication and I have to use CCS C For PIC for programming and Proteus for simulation. My problem is: There is only RS232 library in CCS C and Proteus doesn't have Max485 either. Can I use RS232 library for RS422 (since they work similarly), and can I use Max487 instead of Max485 in simulation?

I will design the real life circuit after simulation so I don't want to risk it not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RS232 and RS422 are two different descriptions of the hardware layer only. RS232 uses different voltage/logic levels, whereas RS422/RS485 uses differential signals. On the data link layer, both use UART frames. Your microcontroller/software won't know or care if you hook up a bare UART (TTL levels), a RS232 transceiver or a RS422 transceiver.

(RS422 generally means full duplex point-to-point though, whereas RS485 can be "multidrop" semi-duplex with one node at a time sending. So there's a difference there on the higher application layers.)

The only times the software need to know the transceiver is if you dabble with chip selects/current saving or use hardware handshaking signals.

> I will design the real life circuit after simulation so I don't want to risk it not working.

If you don't have much experience in hardware design, you *will* have to go through multiple board spins - even seasoned EE rarely ever get everything right on the first attempt. Although to save yourself at least from the most classic mistakes, double check these: getting rx/tx wrong, missing signal ground, missing terminating resistors, no pull-up (internal or external) on UART RX line.

Comment: Btw schematic and/or layout reviews of PCBs are on-topic here, so maybe post it here for review before sending it off to manufacturing.

Comment: Also most oscilloscopes (preferred) or logic analyzers today can decode serial packets.  Will be useful to 'scope some other good RS232, 422, and 485 traffic to compare against yours. What may seem straightforward (it's serial data, just zeroes and ones; how hard can it be?) ends up being pretty complex when all of the variables are factored in.

Answer (score 3):

You are being confused by the naming of the library. There is no such thing as a RS-232 library as MCUs don't have RS-232. MCUs have UARTs which are typically used for communicating over various different electrical interfaces, converted with an interface IC.

If your library just uses the UART, you can use it with any electrical interface such as RS-232, RS-422 or RS-485.